# enabling and disabling clicks using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four buttons which has click able property. Clicking on button will make a div slide down and clicking again on same div should close the div. I want to add a condition like, when I have a div open, the click property on rest of the three buttons should be disabled, what I did is

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    $(".slide" + i).click(function () {
        var openTab = $(this).attr('class');
        openTab = openTab.replace('slide', '');
        var facetGroup = $(this).attr("key");
        if ($('#panel').is(':visible')) {
            buttonCloser(openTab);
        } else {
            buttonOpener(openTab, facetGroup);
        }
    });
}

function buttonCloser(m) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
        if (j != m) {
            //alert(j);
            $(".slide" + j).bind("click");
        } else {
            $(".slide" + j).css({
                "background-color": " #fff5c3",
                "color": "#000000"
            });
        }
    }
    $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
}

function buttonOpener(m, n) {
    for (j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
        if (j != m) {
            $(".slide" + j).unbind("click");
        } else {
            $(".slide" + j).css({
                "background-color": "#293345",
                "color": "#fff5c3"
            });
        }
    }
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
    refreshFacet(n);
}
```

The problem with this code is that the first time I open a div by clicking on slider, the other three click events are disabled, bt when I close that div, it will nt re-enable its click property. so it wont open anything..

Comment: What's your (relevant) mark-up?

Comment: I did nt get you, mark up in the sense...

Comment: What does your HTML look like? What buttons are meant to be affected by this script?

Comment: .slide1-4 are the button ids.. and panel is the div that opens up on clicking button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your actual mark-up, I'd suggest that you use simple jQuery, rather than mixing and matching between 'plain' JavaScript and jQuery:

```
var buttons = $('button[class^="slide"]'),
    panel = $('#panel');

$(buttons).click(
    function() {
        var that = $(this);
        if (panel.is(':visible')) {
            if (that.hasClass('opener')) {
                panel.slideToggle();
                that.removeClass('opener');
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            panel.slideToggle();
            that.addClass('opener');
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QPtRP/).

---

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [attribute begins with selector `attribute^="value"` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-begins-with-selector/).
- [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).